# SwiftUI Animation's timingcurve creation

Tags: swift, swiftui

Along with predefined animation curves these is an option to set a timing curve using [timingcurve(*:*:*:*:duration:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animation/timingcurve(_:_:_:_:duration:)).
What is the meaning of its parameters (`c0x`,`c0y`, `c1x`, `c1y`)? How is the curve built? Documentation is lacking.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote and close vote? Would the voter like to explain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm only guessing as much as I can with the information we're given.

From the docs...

`static func timingCurve(_ c0x: Double, _ c0y: Double, _ c1x: Double, _ c1y: Double, duration: Double = 0.35) -> Animation`

It looks like the four numbers are actually a pair of x, y coordinates.

```
c0 = (c0x, c0y)
c1 = (c1x, c1y)
```

We also know that this is going to generate an easing curve which will start at time 0, animation %age 0 and end at time 1, animation %age 100.

So... I'm guessing these parameters are control points for a cubic bezier curve.

We would have four control points.

1. The start point (0, 0)
2. The first parameter c0
3. The second parameter c1
4. The end point (1, 1)

So, you need to provide the control points to generate the cubic curve that would describe the timing curve that you would like to use.

You can use this website https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.82,.38 to have a look at how those properties change the curve.

As a basic example a timing curve like "ease-in-out" with a duration of 1 second would use parameters like...

`timingCurve(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1, duration: 1.0)`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, looks like cubic spline coefficients indeed, @Fogmeister. Thanks for interactive visualizer link. Useful for tuning. Found a helpful gist to do similar task and familiarize oneself with different animation curves in Xcode: https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/f1bfea3b26ed23c26f2b016a2d618ba4

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an interactive Cubic Bezier Generator from which you can get the coefficients for timing curves that are not ease in ease out, linear, etc.  I personally used it to get a “fast in”  “slow out” curve.

https://www.cssportal.com/css-cubic-bezier-generator/

At that link, you can type in my control points to see the shape of the fast in slow out curve: (controlPoints: 0.03, 0.58, 0.0, 0.9)

Here is some Swift code (not SwiftUI) that takes a `UIImageView` photo that has been zoomed into, panned, and animates with the "fast in," "slow out"  timing curve to shrink it back to normal size and centered on the screen.

Note that the timing function gets specified as follows:

```
scale_Y_Animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.03, 0.58, 0.0, 0.9)
```

I had to use 4 animations, one each for the position change in X and Y of the center, one each for the scale change in X and Y.

```
let currentScale = guessWhatItIsImageView.transform.a
let currentCenter = guessWhatItIsImageView.center

let finalCenter = screenCenterPoint

let scale_X_Animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.x")
scale_X_Animation.duration = guessTimePeriod
scale_X_Animation.fromValue = currentScale
scale_X_Animation.toValue = 1
scale_X_Animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.03, 0.58, 0.0, 0.9)
scale_X_Animation.fillMode = .forwards
scale_X_Animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
guessWhatItIsImageView.layer.add(scale_X_Animation, forKey: "transform.scale.x")

let scale_Y_Animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.y")
scale_Y_Animation.duration = guessTimePeriod
scale_Y_Animation.fromValue = currentScale
scale_Y_Animation.toValue = 1
scale_Y_Animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.03, 0.58, 0.0, 0.9)
scale_Y_Animation.fillMode = .forwards
scale_Y_Animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
guessWhatItIsImageView.layer.add(scale_Y_Animation, forKey: "transform.scale.y")

let position_X_Animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
position_X_Animation.duration = guessTimePeriod
position_X_Animation.fromValue = currentCenter.x
position_X_Animation.toValue = finalCenter.x
position_X_Animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.03, 0.58, 0.0, 0.9)
position_X_Animation.fillMode = .forwards
position_X_Animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
guessWhatItIsImageView.layer.add(position_X_Animation, forKey: "position.x")

let position_Y_Animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
position_Y_Animation.duration = guessTimePeriod
position_Y_Animation.fromValue = currentCenter.y
position_Y_Animation.toValue = finalCenter.y
position_Y_Animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.03, 0.58, 0.0, 0.9)
position_Y_Animation.fillMode = .forwards
position_Y_Animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
guessWhatItIsImageView.layer.add(position_Y_Animation, forKey: "position.y")
```

Comment: Interesting ancient low level animation stuff. 

Comment: An example of the fast in slow out timing curve in use on an image, uploaded to Tik Tok : https://www.tiktok.com/@cashapelayer/video/7210504327046221098